# How to find an "invisible" difference in two strings

Tags: postgresql, string-comparison

I have 2 public keys that look exactly the same. The generate the same hex code, the same hash, I tried diff on linux, sublime text, ... everything tells me they are they same EXCEPT when I query one of both doesn't show up when I query for them with postgres.
And when I compare them in a query, the result says they do not match.
I copy and pasted the matching key over the non-matching key in a test copy of the database and when running the same query again, they both show up.
I have no idea how to find the difference. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The matching public key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEA0+sUzFqHZrjRgsrcWSdK
Jfeo0+VMEM1yvL4Etd2zX+TGynlN3Os/JxVk57dzTJBg6QCELYDKbf2e2mE4fDSp
mgvfgViufeLUplYzyPWx18hRua5gkamywieDBwjyj40n3ZccS4OUArlAjH9+u6o2
1z4zWD8lSfwA0qBhI/hh28iFHXLd9XFq34n7j4GRqXAFQPLunUh20O1hHoLf6Day
0XyRKuyBvEVQMM81xD9jPC9Hj4vs/GT1DaksIQCAeNqfyCuOacQc3FOSimneS0W9
fxLyJqO+dCXUo/fBLyhEwE1hloNlkgXGe9S7p5qbmQOvqQZxIuZQJIVOPUd+Loqq
qRWdhaVzXXBYtcODb2IroF2YomFkoFF3VUSVpKCNEOQZ1CvJZWC05tJBmdDXfqMl
WxkygK7OW3ucx1FKOrIK911ZLlMd1r6vWuJhW829X8/Q+s0yljze71yQ1UNFb1ki
djSacjxb8p7E7QX0BpuvWqu6hb4nP836huc1pp89ZqlB1bE0XIOGrHSISUtO+qEE
mSYij2hZmfifpstU7xze4h4xUzxrvWjebIYHaW5b2Xt2RORsOFH9ZfnlufK4pDko
VhZwCaA74sZ9G/t1F2ygR5KBPTrDteu+ou42H2F+0JyAYOXsENZHUX0ikyVHXBMQ
FeZ+NLuyR2Mva9U5DJjaXcsCAwEAAQ==
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

The non-matching public key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

The query:

```
select jane, john, case when jane = john then 'YES' else 'NO' end 
from (
  select jane.pkey_sign jane, john.pkey_sign john
  from users jane
  join users john on john.organization_id = jane.organization_id
  where jane.id = 3357 and john.id = 1877
) usrs
```

The result is 'NO'

Answer (score 1):

Found it using the PSQL commandline tool.
Just query for the public key and print it in the console. It showed me \r at the end of each line in one key and not the other. Problem solved!